# Uploading IPA to Testflight error: Invalid IPA, keychain access group

Tags: ios, code-signing, testflight, codesign

When I try to upload to Testflight, I get the "Invalid IPA: The keychain-access-group..." error. What could I be missing?

I've verified that the application bundle identifier matches in every place I can think of. Archive scheme is set to Release. Here are screenshots of every section I can think of:

Code signing (and no entitlements):
[image: code signing]

Bundle ID:
[image: bundle id]

In the organizer:

[image: archive]

In the Organizer I hit Distribute, then Save for Enterprise or Ad-Hoc, then here's the code signing identity I pick:
[image: distrib]

Comment: Check for multiple entries in your Keychain access is any, may be the certificate, remove the old one..

Comment: Only one certificate in my Keychain access for Distribution.

Comment: What I normally do in this case is try to install the IPA manually to my device using Apple's iPhone Configuration Utility or Apple Configurator (on the mac app store). Those tools will usually spit out some kind of error that would hopefully help you figure it out. If it installs without a problem, I would contact TestFlight Support.

Comment: That was a helpful comment. Thanks. I still wasn't given an error message that specified the problem, but it was nice to simplify the error condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem turned out to be this: I had set my Code Signing Identity correctly in the Project settings, but it was being overridden in the Targets equivalent. Changing the signing identity under Targets corrected the problem. My mistake -- I just wish there were a clearer message about the problem at some point.